# Counting occurrences of a string with grep returns wrong count

Tags: shell, grep

Using `grep` I am trying to search through a CSS file to count all occurrences of declarations like `font-size`, but the wrong count is returned.

Initially, I tried it like this:

```
grep font-size style.css | wc -l
```

And like this:

```
grep -c font-size style.css
```

But both times the count is wrong. Could it be a problem because the CSS file is minified to one line?

Comment: `grep` outputs the line that matches (and `wc -l` counts lines) so both of those should output `1` for a one-line script. Look at the `-o` option to `grep`.

Comment: You should show the sample data that you feed to the commands and the wrong answers that you get and justify why you think you should get a different answer (and what that answer should be).  However, I think it likely that your are thinking of occurrences including several on a single line, where the tools are counting 'lines containing occurrences' rather than 'occurrences'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try option `-o` with GNU grep as noted by Etan Reisner:

```
grep -o font-size style.css | grep -c .
```